# How to enable Vulnerability alerts through the GitHub API or GraphQL

Tags: security, github, github-api, github-graphql

I have searched high and low, but I can't find anything telling me how to enable GitHub Vulnerability alerts through their API. I conversely can't find anything saying it's not supported.

Does anyone know where I can find the API documentation if it is supported, or can someone tell me it's not? I have just completed a migration to GitHub for my origination and we have ~750 repositories so enabling them all manually is... less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

we released an API for this scenario a while back, so you can now enable or disable security alerts in bulk using that. We also published a sample which calls that API for all the repositories in an organization.

API: https://developer.github.com/v3/previews/#enable-or-disable-vulnerability-alerts-for-a-repository
Sample: https://github.com/github/enable-security-alerts-sample

Comment: It is all good to present a relevant API of you. Although you should at least document the API call the poster is asking for, here into stackoverflow, even if it is a simplified and point to your own sample code from your API in the end.

Answer (score 0):

@Russ looks like it's only available according to the UI. I am in the same position in needing to enable this for a very large number of repos.

Take a look at: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/Security-vulnerability-alerts/td-p/15846

Answer (score 0):

I got this from my companies GitHub service rep:

> 4. Enable security vulnerability via API (v3 or v4) 
>      I've raised this and currently in conversations with the team that is responsible for
>      this feature to see when this could be addressed. I have to say this
>      is an exception to the GitHub rule of API/Platform first. I apologise
>      for that.